# How to return a promise with ngresource post

Tags: ajax, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, ngresource

Been trying to figure out how to return a promise with ngresource post. I can do it with $http but cant figure this out. I am getting .then is not defined error.

Controller

```
  $scope.addLocation = function (model) {
    var model = $scope.model;
    var promise = DocumentLocation.save(model);

    promise.then(function success(model) {
        console.log(model);
        $route.reload();
        $rootScope.close();
        notificationFactory.success();
    },
    function error(error) {
        console.error(error);
        notificationFactory.error();
    }
    )
};
```

Factory

```
app.factory('DocumentLocation', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/apiDocumentLocation/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET', isArray: false // this method issues a PUT request
    }
}, {
    stripTrailingSlashes: false
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource instances have a [`$promise`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) attribute, they are not promises themselves. Just prefix your `then` call with `$promise`.

```
var promise = DocumentLocation.save(model);

  promise.$promise.then(function success(model) {
  ....
```

Comment: I think this is kind of misleading, since your `promise` is not a promise. I would suggest to change it to: `var promise = DocumentLocation.save(model).$promise;` and then just do `promise.then(...`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should call `.$save()` instead of `.save()`

```
$scope.addLocation = function (model) {
    var model = $scope.model;
    var promise = DocumentLocation.$save(model);

    promise.then(function success(model) {
        $route.reload();
        $rootScope.close();
        notificationFactory.success();
    },
    function error(error) {
        console.error(error);
        notificationFactory.error();
    }
    )
};
```

Refer [This Link](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-resource-for-data-models) for more details.

Hope this could help you. Thanks.